# What does OPENSSL_RAW_DATA do?

Tags: php, encryption

I'm pretty new to PHP encryption (and encryption in general) and I've been reading about using openssl_encrypt() function of PHP.

There's an option to add a flag called OPENSSL_RAW_DATA. What does this actually do and where can I see how PHP uses this in the PHP source code?

Comment: Raw data is binary data. It means you can't read it, since there's no encoding table associated with that data that would make it understandable to humans. It's just numbers, represented in binary notation so it usually looks like gibberish when echoed / displayed. To safely transfer such data over HTTP, we usually encode it using base64.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` just tells `openssl_encrypt()` to return the cipherText as ... raw data. By default, it returns it Base64-encoded.

The source code is [easy to find](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L6409), but not really useful as it's not like the flag does anything extra ... The opposite - it tells PHP *not* to do the extra step of Base64 encoding.

Comment: so if I have: base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, "aes-256-cbc", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA)); This just makes sure that the data is encoded in base64 because openssl_encrypt could have used a different encoding than the default, right?

Comment: No ... it makes sure that the data is NOT encoded at all. You get the raw binary representation.

Comment: Well I'm kinda sad to finally read this -- I'm passing in OPENSSL_RAW_DATA to get the raw data, then I'm passing the raw data into base64_encode. I could have skipped a step by NOT passing in the constant! Well hey, the code is working, I'm not "fixing" it!